Is this a good schematic for the W25Q128JVSIM flash memory?
I'm designing a PCB and need additional flash memory for the firmware, so I've chosen the W25Q128JVSIM flash memory(datasheet) and plan to use standard SPI. I've connected both the IO2 (/WP) and IO3 (/HOLD) pins to pull-up resistors, keeping them HIGH by default to ensure the /WP pin is inactive and the /HOLD pin allows normal operation. Additionally, I've included a 100nF ceramic decoupling capacitor for noise reduction and power supply stabilization, as it's recommended to place a 100nF capacitor between the VDD and GND pins of each IC. Is this design correct for using this IC, or is there something I've missed?


Positive voltages on top! Flip R14/R16 and their 3V3-symbol.
